# Why doesn't my hangman game work the way it's supposed to

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
import sys

word_list = ['zebra',  'memory']

guess_word = []
secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
lenght_word = len(secret_word)
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
letter_storage = []

def play_func():
    print('Great moment to play HANGMAN!')

    while True:
        game_choice = input('Do you want to play? ').lower()

        if game_choice == 'yes' or 'y':
            break
        elif game_choice == 'no' or 'n':
            sys.exit('That is a shame! BYE!')
        else:
            print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')
            continue

play_func()

def change():
    for character in secret_word:
        guess_word.append("-")

    print('The word you need to guess has', lenght_word, 'characters')
    print('Be aware that you can only enter 1 letter from a-z')
    print('If you want to exit type quit')
    print(guess_word)

def guessing():
    guess_taken = 0
    while  guess_taken < 8:
        guess = input('Pick a letter: ').lower()

        if guess == 'quit':
            break
        elif not guess in alphabet:
            print('Enter a letter from a-z')
        elif guess in letter_storage:
            print('You have already guessed that letter')
        else:
            letter_storage.append()
            if guess in secret_word:
                print('You guessed correctly!')
                for x in range(0, lenght_word):
```

I think the problem is here:
besides from no
                        if secret_word[x] == guess:
                            guess_word[x] == guess
                            print(guess_word)
                    if not '-' in guess_word:
                        print('You Won!')
                        break
                else:
                    print('The letter is not in the word. Try Again!')
                    guess_taken += 1
                    if guess_taken == 8:
                        print('You Lost, the secret word was: ', secret_word)

```
change()
guessing()
print('Game Over!')


if secret_word[x] == guess:
    guess_word[x] == guess

I think the problem is on these lines of code because they don't actually replace guess_word
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully get you on the right track. I just created a new method/function to contain all of your other functions, and fixed the append statement. Good Luck!

```
import random
import sys

word_list = ['zebra',  'memory']

guess_word = []
secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
lenght_word = len(secret_word)
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
letter_storage = []



def main():
    play_func()
    change()
    guessing()


def play_func():
    print('Great moment to play HANGMAN!')

    while True:
        game_choice = input('Do you want to play? ').lower()

        if game_choice == 'yes' or 'y':
            break
        elif game_choice == 'no' or 'n':
            sys.exit('That is a shame! BYE!')
        else:
            print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')
            continue


def change():
    for character in secret_word:
        guess_word.append("-")

    print('The word you need to guess has', lenght_word, 'characters')
    print('Be aware that you can only enter 1 letter from a-z')
    print('If you want to exit type quit')
    print(guess_word)

def guessing():
    guess_taken = 0
    while  guess_taken < 8:
        guess = input('Pick a letter: ').lower()

        if guess == 'quit':
            break
        elif not guess in alphabet:
            print('Enter a letter from a-z')
        elif guess in letter_storage:
            print('You have already guessed that letter')
        else:
            letter_storage.append(guess)
            if guess in secret_word:
                print('You guessed correctly!')
                for x in range(0, lenght_word):
                    print(x)

main()
```

Comment: The code is better writen but it still doesn't work correctly

Comment: It doesn’t actually finish the game, but it did make the code you wrote run with no errors. I was under the impression you still had to finish the game in the for loop in the guessing method.